# What specifications does a macro lens need for a Thermal Seek CompactPro?

Tags: macro, macro-lenses, infrared

I'm getting into repairing electronics and would like to be able to look closer at failing components. The Zink Selenide lenses, that are being sold, are insanely overpriced. I can't find the focal length and diameter required for the lens, so I can order just the lens cheap.

Comment: I assume ZnSe is used in lenses to have good IR transmission. Using a regular lens is not going to work...

Comment: Please explain how this is related to photography.

Comment: @xiota "Photography is the art, application, and practice of creating durable images by recording light, either electronically by means of an image sensor [...]" I want to create a durable image by recording light that is close to the spectrum of visible light by means of an image sensor and a lense

Comment: @xenoid I assume the same principles apply, like ior focal length etc., im basically asking which focal length, diameter  and type of lense I need

Comment: Your question states that you're "getting into repairing electronics and would like to be able to look closer at failing components."  There is nothing there about taking photographs.

Comment: This question is about applicable lenses to use on a thermal camera. The camera can be used for both pictures and video, so there is some overlap but I do think it's on-topic to discuss the requirements for thermal imaging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a ZnSe convex or planoconvex lens. Placing it in front of your existing lens will allow it to focus closer.

Search for "ZnSe lens" on your favorite shopping sites. Many are listed as condenser lenses for CO<sub>2</sub> lasers for around $15-20.

Make sure the diameter is large enough to cover the front element of your existing lens.  Thare aren't really any other relevant specs since you'd be using it as an auxiliary lens to modify the function of your existing lens.

See YouTube: [DIY Macro Mode for a Seek Thermal Camera](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=RwXIHRWuvN4)

Comment: Works pretty nicely